# connecting to port using TcpListener class

Tags: c#, network-programming

** I don't have much experience with sockets and network develop - so im sorry if this question is not very good ...

I have some hardware that connected to my computer ( i see this hardware as network card ). 
This hardware is sending some strings using TCP protocol ( sending always to port 551 ).

New, i need to get those string in my application. 
So i want to use the 'TcpListener' object  to listen to localhost protocol - listen to port 551.

In the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) i see that i can initialize the 'TcpListener' object so it will listen always to port 551 ( first constructor ).

But the hardware is also connected to port 551 - because its need to be send the strings -

So how can i do it ? 
what is my basic misunderstanding ?

Comment: Is the device accepting incomming connections on port 551, or only connects to others using that port? If it's just connecting to others, it doesn't actually use that port itself. It's like your web-browser connects to some server on port 80, the browser doesn't use port 80, the server does.

Comment: The device is seen as network card - and its defined with some ip address ( 192.168.0.1 ). So, i have now two network cards on my computer - ( the second is the regular network card that i using for the internet connection ) -

Comment: If it's acting as a network card with a specific ip-address, then you can create a listening socket (e.g. using the `TcpListener` class) bound to that specific ip-address.

Comment: Ok , but do i need to deal with the default gateway or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure I have the setup correct:

So you have some hardware sending it out on port 551, say on IP Address 192.168.1.1.
You added a second card, with, say, IP Address 192.168.1.2.

In order to listen to what 192.168.1.1 is sending you need to:

1) Make sure 192.168.1.1 is sending its TCP Packets to port 551 on 192.168.1.2.

2) Open a TCPListener, binding the listener to 192.168.1.2:

```
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2");
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr , 551);
```

3) Sit and wait until server finds something coming in on that port:

```
server.Start();
...
server.AcceptTcpClient();
```